# Rails: introducing inverse_of constraints in existing models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I maintain a large Rails 4.1 codebase with tens of model classes and various relationships between these. I recently discovered the `ActiveRecord` `inverse_of` constraint on `has_many` / `belongs_to` relationships (and indeed has_one relationships). None of such relationships in my models currently have `inverse_of` enforced but since I am on 4.1, I am assuming that Rails automatically deduces these relationships wherever it can. But can adding `inverse_of` relationships now cause any failures?

1. I can only think of scenarios where without `inverse_of`, two different instances of an object referring to the same underlying record could be inconsistent state if we edit them differently and try to save them. But is there a caveat when all references refer to the same instance?
2. Could partial application of inverse_of - only to some `has_many` / `belongs_to` relations and not others, cause a problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Rails now automatically detects inverse associations. If you do not
>   set the :inverse_of option on the association, then Active Record will
>   guess the inverse association based on heuristics.
>
> There are limitations to :inverse_of support:
>
> does not work with :through associations.
>
> does not work with :polymorphic associations.
>
> inverse associations for belongs_to associations has_many are ignored.